# How to return the struct data

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

How to return the struct data

```
struct Transaction  {
  address from;
  address payable to;
  uint amount;
}
```

I am returning like this

```
function transactionDetails() external view 
        returns(address, address, uint) {
    address from;
    address to;
    uint amount;
    return (from, to, amount);
}
```

But it showing

```
0: address: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1: address: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2: uint256: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the structure as a public variable. As we know public variable in solidity is constant read method.

```
struct Transaction  {
  address from;
  address payable to;
  uint amount;
}

Transaction public tx;
```

Now call tx() method to get the value of the structure's elements.